# Is there a known algorithm for finding which K elements out of N elements have a sum that is closest to a whole number?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math, time-complexity

As a small example, say I have `N=6` elements

```
{ 0.03, 0.25000039, 1.391, 500.1, 0.5000001, 1.75001  }
```

and `K=3` then the combination `{ 0.25000039, 0.5000001, 0.2500001 }`, which sums up to `1.00000059` would be the combination that sums up the closest to a whole number.

Is it possible to solve this without "brute force" (iterating through all `n choose k` elements)?

Comment: I think the answers to your two questions are "yes" and "no". There is a known algorithm - "brute force". And hence why the second answer is no.

Comment: This is a variant of the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and is NP-Complete; therefore it has no efficient solution.

Comment: Try limiting the sum as a polynomial f(n). It may help...

Answer (score 1):

I can think of this:

1. Have a target. Initially target is the number you want to get to.
2. Select the biggest number smaller than or equal to target.
3. If there were such a number in previous step reduce the target by that number
4. If target is zero you are done else go to 2
5. Else select the smallest number in the series
6. Reduce the target by that number and check if the absolute value of the target is now bigger than previous target or not if it is you take this last number if it is not you leave it and your current series before the last number is the answer.

Up to here it's giving a close answer. To make it 100% you then repeat the same process this time without the biggest number. Also I omitted this in the algorithm that whenever you want to select a new number if there are no numbers left you are done and that's as close as you can get. Why I left this out is because you might want to allow a number to appear multiple times and therefore you don't need this part.

This is something I came up with. It might need some testing and if you think it's wrong please tell me in the comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this task can be reduced to classical [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). So the solution as we know it would be NP-complete.

Comment: It surely look similar, but can you show how it can be reduced? For me the reduction is non-obvious at the first sight. Also we are talking here about optimization problem, not decision problem, so related knapsack problem is not NP-complete but NP-hard. Doesn't help much, though...

Comment: I'm not a mathematician so may be wrong )
To me this seems like we a have an 'infinite' set of knapsacks of sizes 1, 2, 3...
And also we have a set of elements we want to put into one of the knapsacks. 
Considering that task allows us to find a combination that slightly exceeds knapsack size, we may assume that we also have some 'virtual' element of size <1. Using this element we'll have to find a combination that suit size S + 1 instead of S.
So in common case it is even harder that knapsack problem itself.

Comment: The fact that we have predifined number of element we have to use (K) simplifies the solution, but still I don't think the best match can be found without going through all possible combinations, which are O(N!).
In case approximative solution is good enough, I'd suggest looking for some kind of genetic algorithms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)

Comment: Well, for approximate solutions there are a lot of algorithms for knapsack problem, which probably can be modified for this case. But I'm still wondering how fixed K affects the complexity.

Comment: In case of fixed K we operate with a number of K-combinations from N. With arbitrary number of elements we have to deal with a sum of K-combinations from N for all K from 1 to N, which is obviously larger, as it includes K-combination as well. Anyway, hardly will this help to solve the original problem.

Comment: For fixed K, the complexity should be O(N!/(N-K)!) = O(N^K).
For K=1, it obviously is O(N); for K=2 it is O(N*(N-1)) = O(N^2), ...
So we don't end up at an exponential complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one of my projects, where I had to pick a subset of size `k` out of an original set of size `n`. The subset should satisfy some constraints and maximize (or minimize) a function calculated on the subset.
The problem looks trivial if `n` is small, but as long as `n` greater than `30`, it starts becoming more challenging given a large number of combinations.
Genetic algorithm (GA) is very helpful and practical in this case.
For example, you can follow [this example](https://pymoo.org/customization/subset.html), and it will give the result in 1 minute. What you need is to modify the objective function, e.g.,  `out["F"] = (np.sum(self.L[x]) - target)**2`.
Of course, the GA cannot guarantee an optimal solution, but it should give you at least the near optimal solution quickly.